# Getting error in applying coordinate transformation in ggplot Histrogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that I can successfully generate a histogram of, like so:

```
x <- c(1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 
           1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1082.227051, 1061.021973, 72.625076, 
           893.228271, 605.197388, 15.236160, 1311.000977, 2161.091064, 1.000000, 335.215393, 523.336670, 41.877338,
           467.459686, 1.000000, 1.000000, 751.669617, 20.263149, 2612.868896, 2837.354004, 2214.660889, 31.043751,  
           836.496216, 1419.154053, 84.640457, 2261.688965, 1.000000, 1.533333, 1.000000, 1.155556, 1.000000, 
           1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000)
df <- as.data.frame(x)
names(df)[1] <- 'values'
df$type <- 'test'

ggplot(df, aes(x=values, fill = type)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.7, 
                 aes(y = ..count..),
                 position = 'identity')
```

Which gives me this graph:

[image]

Notice none of the values are negative.  When I apply a log scale to the x-axis,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=values, fill = type)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.7, binwidth=500,
                 aes(y = ..count..),
                 position = 'identity') +
  coord_trans(x="log10")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in if (zero_range(range)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In trans$transform(out$range) : NaNs produced
```

Despite none of the x values producing NaNs when the log is applied to the data separately.

```
> log10(df$values)
 [1] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[13] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 3.03431839 3.02572438 1.86108660 2.95096246 2.78189704 1.18287553 3.11760302 3.33467307
[25] 0.00000000 2.52532395 2.71878117 1.62197907 2.66974416 0.00000000 0.00000000 2.87602700 1.30670694 3.41711762 3.45291352 3.34530724
[37] 1.49197419 2.92246398 3.15202954 1.92757800 3.35443288 0.00000000 0.18563647 0.00000000 0.06279098 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
[49] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: I edited to show my true data set, and checked that none were negative.  I also removed the position=identity, all to no avail.  Can you test it with my actual dataset?

Comment: Yes, same error. Seems it is to do with your data.. i dont know sorry

Comment: huh.. seems the binwidth could be the culprit.. try `binwidth=0.5` .. it takes time

Comment: Yeah, that works.  Any idea why?

Comment: I tdont know.. maybe something to do with the first bar being so close to zero causes problems with the rescale

Comment: It's the zero, it's included in the lowest bin. You could set bin breaks manually by passing in a `breaks` argument to `geom_histogram`. See `?stat_bin`...